# webpy pass parameter from GET to POST

Tags: python, web.py

I'm trying to do bind account.
First I get the user id and return a url like: http://xxxx.com/id=111111
and the page has a form to complete the user's account information.
The form method is post.

he problem is how I can get the id(1111)

the code:

class index(object):

```
def GET(self):
    return render.hello_form()

def POST(self):
    form = web.input(account = '', pswd= '')
    account = form.account
    pswd = form.pswd
    #Problem! I cannot get the id
    id =
```

Thanks.

Comment: Answer it myself. I found this solution: web.ctx.env.get('HTTP_REFERER').split('=')[1]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a unnecessary cost to the server. The best practice is make the minimum number os type requests as possible. I would create a

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='{{user_id}}'>
```

and send this inside my form, to make just a POST request.